# Drag image from desktop and save it in bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, drag-and-drop

My problem is the following: I have a bitmap called secretImage. Now the user can drag an image from their desktop onto a panel and the image is stored in the bitmap.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
bitmap secretImage;

private void pnlImage_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

    }

    private void pnlImage_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        secretImage = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        pnlImage.BackgroundImage = secretImage;
    }
```

The problem is that the effect is not even shown. Therefore I guess that the image (which is *.bmp) is somehow not DataFormats.Bitmap. Maybe my approach is completely wrong, I'm more a beginner in c#.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Have you checked what the DataFormat actually is when you drag the image to youre control?

Comment: Good idea, but how may I do that? :)

Comment: I guessed that and tried that but I couldn't find the DataFormat of the image anywhere there.

Comment: Consider using DataFormats.FileDrop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you actually need is this:

```
    private delegate void DragDropDelegate(String[] s);

    private void pnlImage_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void pnlImage_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] a = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            if (a != null)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new DragDropDelegate(DelegateDragDrop), new Object[] { a });
                this.Activate(); // This avoids some odd behaviour
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error in DragDrop function: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DelegateDragDrop(String[] files)
    {
        // Verify file formats and do something with the files.

    }
```

Since not all images are bitmaps, it wont work allways with DataFormats.Bitmap so better go the other way and use FileDrop, because it contains all dragging files, more specifically file paths in the event.

Invoking the delegate is there to prevent blocking the explorer when working with the files and it also avoids cross thread problems.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed now I can drag the file on there but nothing happens really. That is the DragDropEvent doesn't seem to work. Furthermore I actually want to restrict files so that only *.bmap is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for that.
Though as I'm mentioned I'm a beginner a would like to understand what you actually did. My idea was to simply get the data and put them into my bitmap. Could you explain what you do in principle, like what the idea is :). But thank you anyway for your effort, it's always a great help for beginners.

Comment: Another edit. Please accept the answere when it answered your question.

Comment: Ok, Thank. So I've got one last question: Why do I have to store the file path in a string-array if it is only one string?

Comment: That's just the way Windows handles all file drops.  The user could drag/drop multiple files in one shot so the array covers that possibility.  It doesn't differentiate between a single file drop and a multiple file drop; the array is just the standard approach.